# How to get JavaScript output as string in CefSharp?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to get the output of this javascript string but so far what I have tried did not work

My current code is this. response is blank what I want is 4

```cs
var task = chromiumWebBrowser1.EvaluateScriptAsync("2+2");
            var response = task.Result;
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("output", response));
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: EvaluateScript**Async** - take a careful look at.

Comment: Thank you I found a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EvaluateScriptAsync method returns `Task<JavascriptResponse>`. You can await the Task to obtain the JavascriptResponse object then get the Result or error.

```
JavascriptResponse response = await chromiumWebBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync("1 + 1");

if (response.Success)
{
    var onePlusOne = (int)response.Result;
}
else
{
    var error = response.Message; 
}
```